# Why isn't my Python 3 code working? (Class & Objects)

Tags: python-3.x, class, object

I learning Python 3 through Learn Python The Hard Way. I am on ex.40 and learning how to create CLASSES. I typed the code below and when I tried to run in PowerShell. There was no output. Can someone help me understand where the issue is?

```
class mystuff(object):
    def __init__(self,income,spend): #defining variablies within mystuff class (object):
        self.income = income
        self.spend = spend

    def net(self):
        self.income - self.spend


Income = 10000
Spend = -6000
December = mystuff(Income,Spend)

December.net()
```

Comment: Your code writes nothing to the standard output device, so you shouldn't expect to see anything

Answer (score 0):

First mistake in your code is your not using CamelCase for class name though it will run but it's bad practice of code writing.
Second mistake is your not returning the result of function net.
Third mistake is your just running the class but not printing it. Your not using print command to print the output of class.

Improved Code

```
class Mystuff(object):
    def __init__(self, income, spend):   #defining variablies within mystuff class (object)
        self.income = income
        self.spend = spend

    def net(self):
        return self.income - self.spend


Income = 10000
Spend = -6000
December = Mystuff(Income, Spend)

print(December.net())
```

I think you were expecting this result to print maybe.